# Connect to MySQL and fetch a list of customers asynchronously using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, async-await, controller, asp.net-web-api

I am connecting with a database and returning values from a Web API controller.  For better performance, I am doing it completely asynchronously with a new task.

Am I doing it the correct way? Am I using correct the `using` statements? Is the await correct in Open, Close connection and `sda.FillAsync`?

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => GetAllCustomers());
}

private async Task <HttpResponseMessage> GetAllCustomers()
{
    DataTable Customers = new DataTable();

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(""))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                await sda.FillAsync(Customers);
            }
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            await con.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
    return ControllerContext.Request
             .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Customers });
}
```

Comment: `ex.Message.ToString();` does this have any purpose other then being pointless? :-)

Answer (score 6):

In `Get()` you do not need to wrap the call to `GetAllCustomers()` into a `Task` because it's already asynchronous:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    => await GetAllCustomers();
```

There is, however, something else to do:

- `GetAllCustomers()` should be renamed `GetAllCustomersAsync()` to inform that it's an asynchronous method.
- `GetAllCustomersAync()` should not be responsible to create the `HttpResponseMessage` because you want to test DB logic separately from controller logic. More on this later.
- You do not need to return an `HttpResponseMessage`, simply return the strongly typed model/view model you're interested to.

In code:

```
public async Task<DataTable> Get()
    => await GetAllCustomersAsync();
```

Now you have to change `GetAllCustomersAsync()` to match the above.

---

Outside a fictional example (or an **extremely simple** application) I'd avoid to directly return `DataTable` and I'd move to a proper data layer. You usually do not want to handle SQL code directly in your business logic, especially because:

- It's error-prone.
- UI requirements may change over time but database may be stable.
- Database may change over time but UI may be stable.
- You do not have any compile-time check.
- It's hard to test business logic without a database.

---

According to usual C# naming conventions local variables are camelCase, `Customers` should be `customers`.

You do not need to close a connection if it's wrapped within a `using` statement, disposing the connection will also close it.

---

Even assuming you do not return the model type, for example:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
```

You do not need to go through the `ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse()` thing, simply:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(new { Customers });
}
```

In your catch clause `ex.Message.ToString();` is doing nothing. If you properly had DB logic in a separate layer (let's say in a class `DatabaseServices` just to give a name) you may want to:

```
catch (MySqlException e)
{
    throw new DatabaseException("Cannot read customers", e);
}
```

Where `DatabaseException` is a custom exception you use through your data layer. Your controller (simplified without async stuff):

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DatabaseService())
            return Ok(new { Customers = GetAllCustomers() });
    }
    catch (DatabaseException e)
    {
        return InternalServerError(e);
    }
}
```

Of course in real world there will also be some logging here and there and some logic to recover from known errors...

---

Jumping back to your query method, it might be simplified little bit:

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection("..."))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
{
    try
    {
        await con.OpenAsync();

        var sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var customers = new DataTable();
        await sda.FillAsync(customers);

        return customers;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You do not need to check if connection is closed for a newly created `MySqlConnectionObject()`, it can't happen and your code wil always work as expected but if it was not the case then you will return an empty `DataTable`.

Note that when code will grow and you will *probably* need a better way to build SQL commands (assuming you won't use an ORM). Very first step is to, at least, move them outside in `private const string` fields.

Comment: I'd like to point out you should never use `SELECT * FROM table` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/) as that is more a SQL code review.

Comment: @shoo right, with few exceptions. Expand it and post it as answer, code review is a collective thing!